# youtube api with asp.net (401) Unauthorized error

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api, unauthorized

Everytime i try to use the youtube api i get this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

on this code:

```
public static YouTubeRequest AuthRequest()
    {
        YouTubeRequestSettings Setting =
            new YouTubeRequestSettings("app", "key", "email", "pass");
        Setting.Timeout = 99999999;
        YouTubeRequest _request = new YouTubeRequest(Setting);
        return _request;
    }
```

i acquired the key here : http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard

and the email and password, i checked a few times and they are working fine.

i also registered my application here : https://code.google.com/apis/console

but everytime i try to use the request i get the error, what is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments, and you didn't mention this, but did you replace "app" with the name of your application in the `YouTubeRequestSettings` constructor method? Leaving the code as "app" would prevent access.

**Edit**: I took a look at the [.NET page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet) for the YouTube API and I couldn't find the constructor you are using. The only constructors that they list are:

- `YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey)`
- `YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey, (String) SessionToken)`
- `YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", clientID, developerKey, username, password)`
- `YouTubeRequestSettings("NETUnittests", this.ytClient, this.ytDevKey, this.ytUser, this.ytPwd)`

Comment: See if the additions I made to the answer help

Comment: Were you able to reference the API page I linked to when you first added the API?

Comment: I also found a similar question on SO that might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759032

Comment: unfortunately none of these suggestion solved the problem. as for the constructor i have using it for a while (other application) and it works fine. thanks

Comment: i forgot to mention that with the development account everything works fine.