# Error Uploading Video to YouTube

Tags: c#, video, upload, youtube

I am using following code to upload a video to YouTube.
It always gives following error.

```
 The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

My Code is

```
        YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
        YouTubeRequest request;
        string devkey = YouTubeDeveloperKey;
        string username = YoutubeUserName;
        string password = YoutubePassword;
        settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("VideoEditor", devkey, username, password) { Timeout = -1 };
        request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

        Video newVideo = new Video();

        newVideo.Title = Title;
        newVideo.Description = Description;
        newVideo.Private = true;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(FilePath, "video/flv");
        Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Please do you have any idea about this error

Comment: Can you show the xml that is returned ?

Comment: How can I get the XML ? It gives error at line Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);

Comment: Set a breakpoint at that line and `step-into` the code.

Comment: Ok, After where can I find the XML

Comment: You have to figure that yourself. I haven't used Youtube video upload code till now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Youtube API V2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses), error `403` is an `authorization error`.

Most probably the username and password might be wrong.

My guess: Did you enable two step authentication on your Google account ? 
If so, you must use an [application-specific password](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en&hide_authsub=1).

Comment: No, I didn't enable two step authentication , Username and Password correct, I can log into YouTube using the browser

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint at `request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);` and hover over `settings` to see its value and make sure that the username and password are what you are expecting them to be.

Comment: And please look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759032/how-to-use-the-youtube-api-login-procedure-using-c) already asked on SO and confirm to yourself that you are sending the right credentials. And also follow the answer in [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759032/how-to-use-the-youtube-api-login-procedure-using-c).

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to your youtube application via https://console.developers.google.com then select your application go to APIs and auth -> APIs.
It will display a list of multiple available APIs, click on Youtube Data API, and then click "enable". This will enable this API to be used by your app and most likely will solve your issue.