# upload video to youtube using a simple ASP.NET application and oAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I've been reading plenty of here and there examples on how to use the Gdata API to upload a video file to youtube, but none are crystal clear.
Is there a simple clear example on how to do this?
Basically I have an asp.net page, with a login to youtube link, when the user clicks the link he will be prompted to enter his credentials. After successful login, he will be redirected to the asp.net page where he selects his video file and uploads it to youtube.

Answer (score 0):

GData was turned off 3 weeks ago.  You have to use the data api v3.  Here's some example code:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

Comment: That link contains an example.

Comment: it is a windows forms example

Comment: me too looking for the same..but not able to find the issue in my code..can any one plz help me here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593609/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube-using-google-apis-youtube-v3-and-c