# .NET YouTube Google APIs upload credential error

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, youtube-data-api

I have been attempting to setup the Google APIs to upload a video to YouTube.

I have gone to as basic a setup I can.

1. Setup a CLI project in VS2017
2. Use NuGet to install YouTube v3
3. Copy the YouTube Sample code exactly as it is from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video)
4. download my `client_secrets.json` from the API page (both web and installed versions, the installed version is what I am using)

If I remove the `try` `catch` this is the detailed error I get

```
System.AggregateException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples.UploadVideo.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\CHALICE_ITDept\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 31

Inner Exception 1:
TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""
```

If I set up the same code as a web project, and use my `web` keys, the page just hangs and does nothing.

I have however been able to use my `web` keys with the Javascript sample code, and it works fine.

My goal with the project I am working on is to have my user (from a password protected page) upload their video directly to my YouTube Account.  I then store the video ID to re-embed back on my webpage.  I want to do this without the user having to sign into a google account.  So I will be storing my own access/authentication/refresh/etc token.... but I havent got that far yet.

I can't get passed the `credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` point, and I don't know why.

If I try using the `web` keys, the URL redirect will always fail because the port the VS uses is randomized so I can't add it to the 'Authorized redirect URIs'

Answer (score 0):

So, hello random.  I generated a whole new set of O'Auth API keys and now it works.....